# Duplicate symbol for class in library and project

Tags: objective-c, xcode, symbols

I am using SBJson classes in my library and having tried to use the library in my project I am having a duplicate symbol error because I am also using these files in the main project.

I can't add prefixes to these files so how does one usually work around this problem ?

I saw other answers that suggest renaming classes with prefixes, yet this isn't really the solution since it's correct that these files have duplicates - it's an open source code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could remove the SBJSON (.m) files from the *library project **target*** (using the *"Build Phases"* screen in Xcode) and then project should be able to compile using the SBJSON files that are part of the *main project*. There might be issues though, if both projects use different versions of the SBJSON library.

Personally I wish all library projects didn't include other libraries but note (in a *"Read Me"* file or whatever) that it's a dependency and it's up to the developer to include the dependencies in the main project. I've had a lot of issues with duplicate symbols in the past due to this stuff.

Comment: It's true... I could keep my dependancy during development and exclude it from the target, this is essentially what happens for frameworks and third party libraries anyway.

Comment: Perfect. I was using two third party libraries that had the same component. This did the trick ;)

Answer (score 1):

Just Go to **Build Setting** and

search for **No Common Blocks** and

set it **NO**.

And build again you will not get this error again.

CheersKP

Answer (score 0):

You can just include the .h files in your project and remove .m for SBJson. That way you can import the .h in you code and it will compile.